# How to use a class method as a closure without holding a strong reference to self in that method/closure?

Tags: swift, memory-management, retain-cycle

I have a class :

```
class myVC:UIViewController {
    let myButton = MyButton()
    func viewDidLoad() 
    {
         view.addSubview(myButton)
         myButton.addTarget(myMethodClosure) // ***
    }

    func myMethodClosure() // I guess this method captures self strongly when im using it as a closure, tell me if im wrong 
    {
        self.doingStuffs() 
    }
}
```

My Button Class :

```
class MyButton:UIView {
    var cbk:(()->Void)?
    init() 
    {
        // ... 
        addTapGestureRecognizer(#selector(onPress)) 
    }
    func addTarget(_ cbk:()->Void))
    {
        self.cbk = cbk
    }
    func onPress() {
        // execute animation of the button 
        // ... and after it :  
        self.cbk?() 
    }
}
```

When I present `myVC` and then dismiss it after, the VC is not deallocated. I guess this is because myMethodClosure, taken like a closure (not a method) on line *** holds a strong reference on self (that is : myVC). 
So it gets like :

```
rootview -> myVC -> myButton -> myMethodClosure(held in variable cbk)
              ^                        |
              |                        | 
              --------------------------
```

So as myVC has 2 references it does not get deallocated when rootview release its reference to it with `rootview.dismiss()`

My question is : when I pass the method as a closure line //***, how to say "I want to pass it like a closure, but holding a weak reference to self" 
I tried this : `myButton.addTarget([weak self] myMethodClosure)`  of course it didn't work...

Comment: There is no provision for saying `[weak self]` anywhere except in an anonymous function.

Comment: So I have to transform my method myMethodClosure into a closure held by a variable ?

Comment: That would certainly work. There are other points to break the cycle too.

Comment: I got error 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '(myVC) -> () -> myVC' when transforming my method into closure variable

Comment: I finally did myButton.addTarget({ [weak self] self?.myMethodClosure }) but is there a less verbose manner to say that ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't find that "verbose".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, it's simplest to see what's going on here by eliminating all the unnecessary dross. Here's a reduced version of what you're doing:

```
class MyVC:UIViewController {
    let myButton = MyButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(myButton)
        myButton.cbk = myMethodClosure
    }
    func myMethodClosure() {
        print(self)
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
class MyButton:UIView {
    var cbk:(()->Void)?
}
```

We can test that by saying

```
let what = MyVC()
what.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

At that point, `what` goes out of existence, but `"deinit"` is not printed. We've got a retain cycle. The MyVC instance has a strong reference to the MyButton instance thru `myButton`, but the MyButton instance has a strong reference to its `cbk` function which has a strong reference to the MyVC instance (because the function refers to `self`).

There are various ways to break the cycle, but if you want to do it at the level of the function, you need to express the function as an anonymous function so that you can take advantage of `[weak self]`:

```
myButton.cbk = { [weak self] in self?.myMethodClosure() }
```

There probably really isn't any really good reason why a function with a name (i.e. defined by `func`) can't have a capture list, but currently Swift has no provision for doing that.

Comment: Thanks for these further explanations:)

Comment: Any other way to break the retain cycle ?

Comment: Maybe not. A subview with a strong reference to its superview / view controller is basically always a bad idea...

Comment: Ppl always say that but as I develop my project I find many situations where a reference to the superview seems to simplify things.. If I present a VC, and I want to dismiss it, if I don't hold a weak rootVC reference within this presented VC, I'm obliged to do all the delegate stuffs like create a protocol, set its default implementation etc.. for only one little function : dismiss the presented VC...

Comment: "If I present a VC, and I want to dismiss it, if I don't hold a weak rootVC reference within this presented VC, I'm obliged to do all the delegate stuffs like create a protocol, set its default implementation etc.. for only one little function : dismiss the presented VC" There are other ways to deal with that, but that would be another question. From the point of view of _this_ question, you merely prove my point, since the delegate reference should be weak.